# Android Studio connect ADB via Ethernet

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to connect the ADB via Ethernet from within the Android Studio IDE? The device I have to use has no USB slave ports.

Comment: without root on device? no chances ... you need to connect at least once via USB to change config ... with root you can easily download app from Google Play which will do it for you

Comment: the device is configurable so that the ethernet port is accessibile. The description shows a adb command that uses the ethernet port and via the adb command line i can install apps for example. The question is: In Android-Studio (v0.2.5) is there a possibility to use the Ethernet interface and not the USB interface? I have only found a setting that let me switch between USB and Emulator. (Menu Run --> Edit Configutations..., in the dialog Target Device)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp ... it is working for me ...

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been added recently.

Install some *Android-x86* on your Xen/KVM/Virtualbox VM and enable debug there.
Ensure you've got shared bridge connection or virtual network device that can reached from outside of VM and can resolve some network address from your favourite WiFi router.

So resolve some address via root terminal with `dhcpcd`.
There is no `ifconfig` there. Only `ip addr show` and `ip link show`.

Connect with `adb` to 192.168.x.x with `adb connect 192.168.x.x` or whatever

Go to `Run` => `Edit Configurations` => `General` => `Target device`
and choose `Show chooser dialog`

So when you press run - choose your device and have fun.